# What is the the derivatives of the following problem？

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, trace

What is the the derivatives of the following problem?

$f(W)$=$tr(e_a^T(diag((WW^T)^{1/2})W)e_b)$ ***and*** $f(W)$=$tr(e_a^T(diag((WW^T)^{-1/2})W)e_b)$

where $e_a$ and $e_b$ are two unit column vector.
$W\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the matrices $(B,E)$ such that
$$\eqalign{
 &E = e_ae_b^T \cr
 &B^2 = {\rm Diag}(WW^T) \cr
 &B\,dB+dB\,B = {\rm Diag}(W\,dW^T+dW\,W^T) \cr
 &2B\,dB = 2\,{\rm sym}\Big({\rm Diag}(dW\,W^T)\Big) \cr
 &dB =B^{-1}{\rm sym}\Big({\rm Diag}(dW\,W^T)\Big) \cr
}$$ where the funtion $\,{\rm sym}(X)=\tfrac{1}{2}(X+X^T)$

Note that $(B,dB)$ are diagonal and therefore commute with each other.

Write the function in terms of these matrices. Then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= E:BW \cr
df &= E:B\,dW + E:dB\,W \cr
 &= BE:dW + EW^T:dB \cr
 &= BE:dW + EW^T:B^{-1}{\rm sym}\Big({\rm Diag}(dW\,W^T)\Big) \cr
 &= BE:dW + {\rm Diag}\Big({\rm sym}(B^{-1}EW^T)\Big)W:dW \cr
 &= \Big(BE + \tfrac{1}{2}{\rm Diag}(B^{-1}EW^T + WE^TB^{-1})W\Big):dW \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}
 &= BE + \frac{1}{2}{\rm Diag}\big(B^{-1}EW^T + WE^TB^{-1}\big)W \cr
}$$
In the above, the trace/Frobenius product is represented by a colon, i.e. 
$$\eqalign{A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)}$$

**Update**

The Diag() operation in the final result can be simplified to yield 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial W} = BE + B^{-1}{\rm Diag}\big(EW^T\big)W$$

Comment: Greg, I am confused with the definition of $B^2 = {\rm Diag}(WW^T)$. $WW^T$ is a matrix and definition of $B$ is a matrix. Then what does ${\rm Diag}$ do actually?

Comment: @user550103 It's an operation which zeros the off-diagonal terms. Personally, I prefer the Hadamard product notation $\big(I\odot X = {\rm Diag}(X)\big)$ but I used the function notation to be consistent with the OP's terminology.

Comment: $(dWW^T)^T=WdW^T$?

Comment: $E:B\,dW + E:dB\,W = BE:dW + EW^T:dB$ ?

Comment: Those relationships are due to the cyclic property of the trace.